# Sympy returning NaN values when substituting infinity into expression

Tags: python, sympy, nan, exponent, infinity

I'm trying to use [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org) to show what happens to terms in a matrix as a variable `t` tends to infinity.

For example.

```
from sympy import *
t = Symbol('t')
exp(-t).subs({t: oo})
```

returns `0` which is correct and

```
exp(t).subs({t: oo})
```

returns `oo` (infinity) which is also correct.

However, some expressions return `nan`.  For example:

```
(t*exp(-t)).subs({t: oo})
```

I'm pretty sure above expression should return `0`.  (`N(100*exp(-100))` returns `3.72007597602084e-42`).

Is this a bug or is it really 'Not a Number'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have `oo*0` the result will be NaN. For some expressions like `x**2*exp(-x)` there can be a well defined limit as x goes to infinity. But if SymPy doesn't know what the expression is then it can't know how to evaluate `oo*0`. Consider the following (all examples of `0*oo`):

```
In [1]: (x*exp(-x)).limit(x, oo)                                                                                                                              
Out[1]: 0

In [2]: (x**2*exp(-x)).limit(x, oo)                                                                                                                           
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: (factorial(x)*exp(-x)).limit(x, oo)                                                                                                                   
Out[3]: ∞

In [4]: (exp(x)*exp(-x)).limit(x, oo)                                                                                                                         
Out[4]: 1
```

If you want to calculate a well defined limit then use the `limit` function/method. Otherwise `0*oo` is not well defined so it will evaluate to NaN.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks.  This works for single expressions.  Is there a way to do `M.limit(t, oo)` where `M` is a matrix?  (I tried `limit(M, t, oo)` and got `NotImplementedError: Don't know how to calculate the mrv of 'Matrix...`).

Comment: I don't get that error when using the limit method `M.limit(x, oo)`

Comment: Strangely, I don't have the error now myself.  No worries, thanks, this is the correct answer I think.